# Most efficient way to use different members of struct in a function?

Tags: c, struct

I'm writing for a very limited resource embedded processor. I have a struct that captures a time series of events, and I'd like to use the same graphing function against different values of different types. Something like (very stripped down; don't sweat uninitialized values, etc):

```
#define GRAPH_ONE 1
#define GRAPH_TWO 2

struct _event_t {
  unsigned long timestamp;
  int sensorOne;
  float sensorTwo;
}

typedef struct _event_t event_t;

event_t[10] MyEvents;

void GraphSensor(byte graphType) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
       // Get minimum value from series
       if (MyEvents[i].?????) ...
    }
}
```

How can I have my function operate on different members of the struct? I can see doing it with a ton of `switch (graphType)` statements, but that's pretty ugly. There could easily be 8 or 10 members of the struct. I could move all of those to a separate function and make every bit of data access call that function, always returning a float (which should be OK for my graph). Finally I could convert to C++ classes, which opens other means.

None of those feel right. Is there a better approach, preferably a very lightweight one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap the accessor you need in a function, and pass that to the function that walks the array and aggregates the results. For example

```
float getSensor1(const event_t* t)
{
    return t->sensorOne;
}

float getSensor2(const event_t* t)
{
    return t->sensorTwo;
}

void GraphSensor(float (*accessor)(const event_t*)) {
    // Get minimum value from series
    float min_value = MAX_FLOAT;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
       float x = accessor(MyEvents + i);
       if (x < min_value)
           min_value = x;
    }
}

/* later on . . . */
GraphSensor(getSensor1);
GraphSensor(getsensor2);
```

You are basically decoupling the access of the data from the operation on it, and homogenizing it all to floats. The aggregation operation could also be encapsulated into a function, too. But that's getting pretty close to map-reduce. :)

Comment: Explain `accessor()` function in the context of C.  Where is it defined? (C++ ?)

Comment: @ryyker:   He doesn't define it, but a clear example of it is the first two functions.

Comment: In my example above, `getSensor1` and `getSensor2` are accessor functions (sometimes called "getters"), since they are used to access data without revealing exactly how that is accomplished. The benefit is that they provide an interface behind which the underlying data structure (`event_t`) is free to change.

Comment: I just looked it up.  I see references on java, C# and C++.  nothing for C though.  I also noticed OP does suggest _convert to C++ classes_.  So perhaps OP tags should include C++ :)  Nice approach. +1

Comment: I'm not surprised you see no references for C. It is more of an OO concept. But just because C does not support OO at the syntax level, it does not mean that you can't borrow concepts from OO and apply them in C. My example above does just that: `getSensor1` and `getSensor2` are essentially _methods_ on the `event_t` _class_, so to speak. Regarding the C++ tag issue, I would argue against adding the C++ tag, since the question is about C, not C++. Until the OP ports his program to C++, or requests a C++ answer, I'd leave the C++ tag out.

Comment: Based on OPs last sentence, I agree.  The C++ tag does not fit.

Comment: @ryyker: `accessor` is a function pointer parameter to the `GraphSensor` function. Basically, callers of `GraphSensor` pass in the address of functions with a matching signature that it should call when it needs them. The last two lines of my example demonstrate this.

Comment: This is clever and I'm pretty sure it fulfills my needs for lightweight. I'll implement and report back. Thanks!
(yep -- I was trying to _avoid_ a C++ conversion, but did recognize it as an option)

Comment: @RandallCook - Your last response cleared it up for me.  I follow.    I have used function pointers, and often in callback fucntions.  I should have seen it earlier.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! It worked beautifully and added < 400 bytes to the compiled program for one sensor, with each additional sensor adding only 80 bytes (~20 of which are strings for titles). Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the struct to an array which uses perhaps all floats.  In that way the data handling is completely homogeneous.

```
#define N_SENSORS   12
#define N_EVENTS    10 

float MyEvents [N_EVENTS] [N_SENSORS];

void GraphSensor(byte graphType)
{
    float min = 1e38;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N_EVENTS; i++)
    {
       // Get minimum value from series
       if (MyEvents[i][graphType] < min)
            min = MyEvents[i][graphType];
    }
}
```

Perhaps the timestamp could be there too in element zero maybe using spreadsheet conventions:  integer part is days since 1970 or 1900 and fractional part is portion of the day (so noon = .5).

Comment: This is clever: +1. My initial reaction was that you lose human-readable names for where your data is in the struct (which is now an array), but you can use `#define`s to name the indices in the array to preserve legibility: `MyEvents[i][SENSOR_ONE]` instead of `MyEvents[i].sensorOne`. This works if all the data can share a common type. If it is heterogeneous, then you may need to use accessor functions.

Comment: It is definitely clever, and I'll save it for future reference. Today, the increase in data size makes it unattractive for this project. Thank you!